# Replace all urls with minified urls within a string containing mixed content

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace-callback

I have string with links and iam going to  extract links into an array as following

```
$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

print_r($match[0]);
```

**results**

```
Array ( 
[0] => http://google.com 
[1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0 
[2] => https://instagram.com/hellow/ 
)
```

Now i will use `bit.ly API` function `gobitly()` for link shorten that ends with `array` like this

```
foreach ($match[0] as $link){
    $links[] = gobitly($link);
}
```

the results of `$links[]`

```
Array ( 
[0] => http://t.com/1xx
[1] => http://t.com/z112
[2] => http://t.com/3431
)
```

Now I want to rebuild the `string` and replace links to the new one to be like this

```
$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://t.com/1xx, http://t.com/z112,http://t.com/3431";
```

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches `\d` so this part `[\w\d]+` can be just `\w+` and `[:punct:]` also matches a comma.

Comment: Just a caution:  At least two 3rd party shortening services I've used in the past are no more.  Completely retired.  If I had done something like the above, and the service becomes extinct, you end up with bit rot.  If you don't record the original urls, you have no recourse.  An alternative is to drop in your own shortening service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the key of the url to be replaced, you can simply loop over then and use `str_replace` to replace each shorturl with the original;

```
<?php

$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

// Shorten array
$short = [ 'http://t.com/1xx', 'http://t.com/z112', 'http://t.com/3431' ];

// For each url
foreach ($match[0] as $key => $value) {
    
    // Replace in original text
    $string = str_replace($value, $short[$key], $string);
}

echo $string;
```

> The text you want to filter goes here. http://t.com/1xx, http://t.com/z112,http://t.com/3431

[Try it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b23587fd0b9261deeef4865f2c00a8b84873684)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to manipulate the matches and return them at once, instead of extracting them and replacing them manually (which would require a bit more work, for no real reason that I can see?). Here's a [quick example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/354438b9f885346e5cfcc7415af5cf6d6caf6a1f)

```
$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

$replaced = preg_replace_callback('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', function($matches){
    // This function runs on each match
    $url = $matches[0];
    
    // Do bit.ly here. This is just an example
    $url = 'url/from/bit.ly/for:'.$url;
    
    // Return the new URL (which overwrites the match)
    return $url;
}, $string );

var_dump( $replaced );
```

This should give you an expected output like:

```
string(191) "The text you want to filter goes here. url/from/bit.ly/for:http://google.com, url/from/bit.ly/for:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,url/from/bit.ly/for:https://instagram.com/hellow/"
```

Of course instead of that weird concatenation I have for example purposes, you'll make a request to bit.ly or whatever API you want and use that shortened URL

Answer (score 1):

You need [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$newString = preg_replace_callback(
    '#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#',
    function ($match) {
        // Use for debugging purposes
        // print_r($match);

        return gobitly($match[0]);    
    },
    $string
);
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/cWmCp), I used `md5` instead of your function.